# Immediate Box (Debug window) Display Separately

Tags: vba, excel

I am really sorry if this is a silly question. I would like to display a message box similar to the `Immediate` window that will sit "always on top" and scroll a countdown while not interrupting the VBA program.

I am essentially crunching numbers for 40,000 rows and each run takes about 15 minutes. I don't know if it's still running or when the current VBA code will complete.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the status bar:

```
Application.StatusBar = "Row " & rowNum & " of " & rowCount
```

At the end, to clear the status bar:

```
Application.StatusBar = False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by displaying **modeless user form**. Below is an example how to do this.

In order to make this example working properly **you need to add new, empty UserForm to your project and change it name to `frmProgress`**.

```
Sub test()
    Dim form As frmProgress
    Dim lblProgress As Object
    Dim i As Long
    '-------------------------------------------------

    'Create an instance of user form and show it modeless on the screen.
    Set form = New frmProgress
    With form
        .Width = 200
        .Height = 60
        .Caption = "Progress"

        'Add label for displaying text...
        Set lblProgress = .Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lblProgress")
        '... and format it to meet your requirements.
        With lblProgress
            .Width = 200
            .Height = 60
            .TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
            .Font.Size = 12
            .Top = 6
        End With

        Call .Show(vbModeless)

    End With




    For i = 1 To 100000

        '(Some code ...)

        DoEvents

        'Here the new text is inserted on the message box.
        lblProgress.Caption = i

    Next i


    Call form.Hide


End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much for this code! it is much appreciated - however I went with the above answer until I finalize the function, then I will be trying to incorporate this code for end users!